# Sending a PHP variable to a new file on button onClick

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to allow download of results (a table) generated when a users searches our inventory. I want to be able to click on a button to download the results into a CSV file.  I am able to generate the CSV file if I add the PHP code directly after I run the query.  However, I need this button to be in a different place on the page and thus I want to be able to call this function sending in the query results rather than directly after the search.

If I do this then I am able to generate the file.

```
function output_csv ($data) {
  $filename = "exportfile.csv";
  $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
  fputcsv($handle, array('UserID','UserName'));
  foreach($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     fputcsv($handle, array($row['UserID'], $row['UserName'])); 
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

I know PHP is a server side so I can't call this function on the onclick if it is on the same page as the button. I was thus thinking I should put this function in a separate file which I can call from the onclick.  But I cannot figure out a way to pass the $data (query results), it keeps on telling me the variable cannot be converted to a string.

```
$file_array=$db->prepare("SELECT UserID, UserName FROM UserProfile");
$file_array->execute();
<button type="button" onclick="download_file.php?pass_array=<?php echo $file_array; ?>)">Click Me</button>
```

My problem is thus that I cannot figure out how to send the results of the query to the output_csv function in my page or another page so that they can be written to the file.

Thanks,

Comment: you can't echo array encode as json and then echo

Comment: @dianuj I don't know how to do json, could you give me a quick example?  Thanks

Comment: Why don't you execute the query on the `download_file.php` file?

Comment: There are many queries which generate the table depending on the search type. I wanted to be able to pass the variables rather than redoing it again.

Comment: Your onclick URI is malformed - it will be onclick="download_file.php?pass_array=1,billy)". You will need to place each item into its on uri variable download_file.php?id=<?...?>&name=<?...?>

Comment: Shouldn't that button be calling the `output_csv()` function, for example `onclick="output_csv();" // extra code` ?

Comment: @Fred, the function is in the download file which checks to see if the variable was sent before calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems:

1. The onclick expects JavaScript, you just give it an URL. Maybe try it with a small form?
2. The `$file_array` is a [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and you have to fetch the data first by [fetchAll()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) or [fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and then encode it with [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).
3. The `foreach` has a wrong format.

Try the following:

```
<?php
$file_array=$db->prepare("SELECT UserID, UserName FROM UserProfile");
$file_array->execute();
?>
<form method="POST" action="download_file.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="pass_array" value="<?php 
        echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($file_array->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM));
    ?>">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

To get the data in the `download_file.php`:

```
function output_csv ($data) {
  $filename = "exportfile.csv";
  $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
  fputcsv($handle, array('UserID','UserName'));
  foreach($data as $row) {
     fputcsv($handle, $row); 
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
$file_array = json_decode($_REQUEST['pass_array']);
output_csv($file_array);
```

Another benefit of the post form is that the data will be transferred in an invisible way. So you don't see really long and strange URLs in the browser. Also the amount of data that could be transferred is a lot higher.

Comment: Yes, it is PDO, sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: how do I get file_array on download_file.php? Via a POST?

Comment: @LuisP Added an example on how to get the data in the second file. How many rows do you expect from your SQL query?

Comment: It depends, from 20 - 100 rows.  I was able to get the file, but now I am getting an error for the fputcsv inside the foreach, it says 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'

Comment: I added it to jsfiddle for your viewing (know it won't work there obviously) - http://jsfiddle.net/dG9LH/

Comment: @LuisP try it with PDO::FETCH_NUM in the fetchAll and just fputcsv($handle, $row);

Answer (score 0):

First place the anchor tag instead of button

```
$file_array=$db->prepare("SELECT UserID, UserName FROM UserProfile");
$file_array->execute();
 $result = $file_array->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
<a  href="download_file.php?pass_array=<?php echo urlencode(json_encode($result)); ?>">Click Me</a>
```

in your download_file.php

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['pass_array'])){
 $arraydata=json_decode(urldecode($_REQUEST['pass_array']));
output_csv ($arraydata);
}
function output_csv ($data) {
  $filename = "exportfile.csv";
  $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
  fputcsv($handle, array('UserID','UserName'));
  foreach($data as $row) {
     fputcsv($handle, array($row['UserID'], $row['UserName'])); 
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Hope it works fine

[**pdostatement.fetch**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: Getting an error on the line calling the output_csv function = PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in download_file.php on line 3

Comment: almost works!  I am now getting an error 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

Comment: weird, error is gone but my output file is three rows: the header, and then one that has a '1' for each column, and the next one has an 'A' for each column.  Not sure if it is relevant, but the 1 is the first number of the first user ID from the query and the A is the first letter from the user name in the query.  Should I also be doing a fetchAll?